# Clear 2nd Dropdown values based on 1st Dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

When I select 1st Dropdown, I need to clear 2nd Dropdown.

I had used `.empty()` method but if I use this method later on I am not getting 2nd dropdown values.

I've tried the following method:

```
     $("#taskcategorylist").change(function () {
        console.log("Task Category Changed");
        $('#tasktypes').val("");
     });
```

1st dropdown Html code:

```
   <div class="field">
       <b>Task Category</b>
       <div class="ui selection dropdown"> 
       <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
       <div class="default text">Select</div>
       <div class="menu" id="taskcategorylist"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

2nd dropdown Html code:

```
 <div class="field">
   <b>Task Type</b>
   <div class="ui selection dropdown">
   <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
   <div class="default text">Select</div>
   <div class="menu" id="tasktypes"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1st dropdown Jquery code:

```
 $.get(window.routemap + "api/task/taskcategory", function (data) {
        self.taskcategorylist = JSON.parse(data.Data).Lookup;
        self.taskcategorylist.forEach(function (item) {
            $('#taskcategorylist').append("<div  class='item' data-value='" + 
            item.category_id + "'> " + item.category_name + "</div >");
        });
    });
```

2nd dropdown Jquery code:

```
$.get(window.routemap + "api/firm/tasktypes", function (data) {
        self.tasktypes = JSON.parse(data.Data).Lookup;
        self.tasktypes.forEach(function (data) {
            $('#tasktypes').append("<div class='item' data-value='" + 
            data.tasktype_id + "'> " + data.task_name + "</div >");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$("#taskcategorylist").change(function () {
    console.log("Task Category Changed");

    $('#tasktypes').parents(".ui.dropdown").dropdown('clear');
});
```

Comment: What's not working?  I'm using the same framework, and I'm using same kind of approach that you are using, this code is working for me, can you show us working demo or snippet, so It would be easy to debug the problem

Comment: Yes its works now i made mistake in the events, your answer exactly works for me has expected, Thank you.